# Evolutionary Optimization Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, optimization, evolutionary-algorithm

I want to optimize following objective function`max f = profit(x,y) - expense(x,y) subject to: 0<= x, y <=1` using strength pareto evolutionary algorithm (SPEA2). The objective function is non-linear and is not convex or concave function of decision variables. Can I break objective function into two that is `maximize profit(x,y)` and `minimize expense(x,y)` and then optimize them in combination at the end. I do not know if it make some sense, sorry I am completely new to the filed. I shall appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: (in general) `profit = income - expense`; and what you've asked looks very dodgy (e.g. `something = profit - expense = income - 2 * expense`), so I'm going to assume you meant "income" everywhere you've said "profit".*

No, you can't find `max. income(x,y)` and `min. expense(x,y)` and combine/optimise them at the end because your can expect a relationship between income and expense (e.g. as expense increases income increases).

Also; don't forget that the best way to approach this kind of problem is to expand and simplify the resulting function.

For a very simple example:

```
income = items * bonus + items * 0.9 * $123.45

expense = bonus * $1 + items * $99.00

profit = income - expense
       = (items * bonus + items * 0.9 * $123.45) - (bonus * $1 + items * $99.00)
       = items * bonus - bonus * $1 + items * 0.9 * $123.45 - items * $99.00
       = (items - 1) * bonus + items * (0.9 * 123.45 - 99.00)
       = (items - 1) * bonus + items * 12.105
```

In other words; if you could find `max. income(x,y)` and `min. expense(x,y)` and combine/optimise them at the end, you still wouldn't want to because it's less efficient/slower, and better/faster to just find `max. profit(x,y)`.

Comment: This is supplementary question which now I face, can we use a  multi objective evolutionary algorithm to solve a single objective optimization problem. Is it possible and also is it reasonable? if not then how we go about it. My preference is to use SPEA2, can I use it to maximize above objective function.